# DateTime.now() returns wrong time(-7:30) in Real Device (Xiaomi Mi 4i)

Tags: datetime, flutter

DateTime.now() returns the wrong time i.e, exactly with a delay of 7:30 hrs. But the same app returns the correct time in Hauwei Nova 3i.

**Steps to Reproduce**

- create a app
- print DateTime.now() in initstate or wherever you want
- run the app in Xioami Mi 4i Android Version(5.02 LRX22G) connected in
  a Wi-Fi

**Output**

> Launching lib/main.dart on Mi 4i in debug mode...
>
> Initializing gradle...
>
> Resolving dependencies...
>
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
>
> Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
>
> Installing build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk...
>
> Syncing files to device Mi 4i...
>
> I/flutter (16029): 2019-06-15 05:54:32.248432
>
> **Flutter Doctor**
>
> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.5.4-hotfix.2, on Linux, locale en_IN)
>       • Flutter version 1.5.4-hotfix.2 at /home/androiddeveloper/flutter
>       • Framework revision 7a4c33425d (7 weeks ago), 2019-04-29 11:05:24 -0700
>       • Engine revision 52c7a1e849
>       • Dart version 2.3.0 (build 2.3.0-dev.0.5 a1668566e5)
>
> [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
>   version 28.0.3)
>       • Android SDK at /home/androiddeveloper/Android/Sdk
>       • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
>       • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
>       • Java binary at: /snap/android-studio/76/android-studio/jre/bin/java
>       • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b16-5323222)
>       ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
>
> [✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
>       • Android Studio at /snap/android-studio/76/android-studio
>       • Flutter plugin version 36.1.1
>       • Dart plugin version 183.6270
>       • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b16-5323222)
>
> [✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.1)
>       • IntelliJ at /snap/intellij-idea-community/152
>       • Flutter plugin version 35.3.3
>       • Dart plugin version 191.7479.14
>
> [✓] Connected device (1 available)
>       • Mi 4i • 97103c6a • android-arm64 • Android 5.0.2 (API 21)
>
> ! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Comment: That returns the time in the local timezone. Check the device timezone in settings.

Comment: @RichardHeap I have checked all the Date and Time Settings. The Settings are prefect. But the DateTime.now() method returns a wrong time...

Comment: Try printing the timezone that the phone reports.

Comment: @RichardHeap I have Printed `DateTime.now().timeZoneName` and it returns `_TZif`

Comment: I have used a package `flutter_native_timezone`  and I got the current Time Zone as `Asia/Calcutta`, But the `DateTime.now()` stills returns a wrong time.

Comment: Sounds like you should enter an issue.

Comment: @RichardHeap I have Created an Issue on github [https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34531 ] , but no one responds :-(

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.now()` should return the [local time](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html) configured on the device. Try updating the Flutter version that you're using by running `flutter upgrade` and see if the issue persists. You can also try using [toLocal()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/toLocal.html) to fetch the local equivalent of the current DateTime being returned.